# vlookup, if value doesn't exist check another column - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sheet1 has a list of SKUs.

```
Sku Column    Formula Column
sku1
sku324
```

Sheet2 looks like the following:

```
Parent Column      Child Column
sku1               sku890
sku2               sku324
```

Result in sheet1:

```
Sku Column    Formula Column
sku1          Parent
sku324        Child
```

I'm trying to do a vlookup and to say: look at Parent Column if SKU exists then return "parent" if not look at Child column if SKU exists then return "child".

Here is the formula I have been working with but haven't got it exactly how I wanted. In its current state it doesn't work at all although I feel I'm close:

```
=IF(iferror(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet8!B:B,1,FALSE),"ERROR"),"PARENT",If((VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet8!A:A,1,FALSE),"CHILD","")))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to your formula:

```
=IF(countif(Sheet2!A:A,A2)>0,"parent",if(countif(Sheet2!B:B,A2)>0,"child","error"))
```

You don't need the vlookup since you're not returning the value.

Comment: This works great. I ended up using a vlookup for the half the formula to get the parent sku of the child. This is the final formula I used: =IF(COUNTIF(Sheet8!B:B,A2)>0,"parent",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet8!A:B,2,FALSE),""))